# What JQuery script is this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, templates

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox

On the right hand side, there are selector tabs (with the selected arrow pointing to the left)

What CSS menu is this? Why can't I find this on the JQuery UI website?

Comment: it's just plain html + css.  No javascript/jquery required.  View source, and/or use your browser's dom inspector.  The left-pointing arrow is just a background image that is applied by a css `a:hover` rule.

Comment: @lee javascript is used to add the class so the li's & a's have the styles.  the class isn't added on the a:hover.  javascript is also being used to load the content into the content area on click.

Comment: @john - You're right, but I should point out that javascript is *not required* in order to render the menu with the left-pointing arrow, and mouse-over effect.  That can all be done via html+css via the `:hover` selector.

Comment: @lee, how? the arrow's being added on click, not on hover

Comment: @john: you're right. I should have said: the mouseover effect can be done with css `:hover`.  The left-pointing arrow can be done with a single css class assigned to the currently selected item.  In a non-javascript enhanced site, each page is loaded from the server separately, and so each page's menu would contain the `selected` class on the correct menu item for that page. I'm not saying "don't use javascript for this", I'm just pointing out that it's not required.  If you do implement this with js, you'll also want to use some form of deep linking (which could be more work than OP wants).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a plugin, it's a simple bit of html/css/javascript that's on the page.

the javascript that controls the menu is in http://jqueryui.com/js/demos.js .

The specific part:

```
//Rewrite and prepare links of right-hand sub navigation
    $('#demo-config-menu a').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('target', 'demo-frame');
        $(this).click(function(e) {

            resetDemos();
            $(this).parents('ul').find('li').removeClass('demo-config-on');
            $(this).parent().addClass('demo-config-on');

            //Set the hash to the actual page without ".html"
            window.location.hash = this.getAttribute('href').match((/\/([^\/\\]+)\.html/))[1];

            loadDemo(this.getAttribute('href'));
            e.preventDefault();

        });
    });
```